# Magento 2 on Product duplicate and save action giving fatal error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

> On duplicate save button product give this following fatal error, what are the issue in database or in some file, I recently migrate m2.2 to M2.3

[image]

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getEntityId() on null in /var/www/html/live/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/ProductUrlRewriteGenerator.php:187 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/live/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/ProductUrlRewriteGenerator.php(141): Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator->generateForGlobalScope(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), NULL) #1 /var/www/html/live/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Observer/ProductProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver.php(71): Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator->generate(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor)) #2 /var/www/html/live/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\ProductProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) #3 /var/www/html/live/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php in /var/www/html/live/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/ProductUrlRewriteGenerator.php on line 187
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the different SKU for it.

Comment: on change SKU same error showing up